# Can not connect to node server

Tags: node.js

I wrote an REST app which working fine on the local machine but not working when on the server. The app server seems to work but when I tried to connect to the default page or any other page I got[server error file or directory not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzAEz.png)

the structure for the app is as shown
[The structure of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQyx1.png)

the www start file seems to work fine but the listning function port is not defined(end of file www blow).
the code for the www start file is generated automatically using  npx express-generator,.
You can see the code for the www here:

```js
#!/usr/bin / env node

/**
* Module dependencies.
*/

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('suu965:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
* Get port from environment and store in Express.
     */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
  * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
* Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
* Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
  */

function normalizePort(val) {
    var port = parseInt(val, 10);

    if (isNaN(port)) {
        // named pipe
        return val;
    }

    if (port >= 0) {
        // port number
        return port;
    }

    return false;
}

/**
  * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
    if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
        throw error;
    }

    var bind = typeof port === 'string'
        ? 'Pipe ' + port
        : 'Port ' + port;

    // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
    switch (error.code) {
        case 'EACCES':
            console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
            process.exit(1);
            break;
        case 'EADDRINUSE':
            console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
            process.exit(1);
            break;
        default:
            throw error;
    }
}

/**
* Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
     */

function onListening() {
    var addr = server.address();
    var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
        ? 'pipe ' + addr
        : 'port ' + addr.port;
    debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

the addr.port seems to be undefine. I couldn't see that an error function  is thrown.

Comment: From the 404 page I can see that it's not just the Node app, there is a reverse proxy. So u need to do proper forwarding. Check out how reverse proxies work and for ur example what u need to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
const app = require("./app");
const debug = require("debug")("node-angular");
const http = require("http");

const normalizePort = val => {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
};

const onError = error => {
  if (error.syscall !== "listen") {
    throw error;
  }
  const bind = typeof addr === "string" ? "pipe " + addr : "port " + port;
  switch (error.code) {
    case "EACCES":
      console.error(bind + " requires elevated privileges");
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case "EADDRINUSE":
      console.error(bind + " is already in use");
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
};

const onListening = () => {
  const addr = server.address();
  const bind = typeof addr === "string" ? "pipe " + addr : "port " + port;
  debug("Listening on " + bind);
};

const port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || "3000");
app.set("port", port);

const server = http.createServer(app);
server.on("error", onError);
server.on("listening", onListening);
server.listen(port);
```

Comment: the same result.